# Problema con migracion base de datos desde MySQL a Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Migré una base de datos desde MySQL a Oracle, utilizando Oracle sql devloper, el problema es que solo migro el esqueleto y no los datos. Eso es normal?.

La operacion la realize desde ORACLE SQL DEVLOPER, cree una conexion a oracle nombre(oracle) otra conexion a mysql nomre(mysql) y entonces migre de oracle a mysql, pero  solo tengo las tablas con las columnas sin ningun dato.

> Pone que datamove complete, pero no esta complete

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿La hiciste online u offline? Hay una sección del wizard de la migración que se llama `Move data` y permite definir qué datos se migran.

Comment: Modo online, en move data tengo la opcion de marcar "truncate" que sera para no mover los datos, pero probe marcandola y sin marcarla y lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

El proceso de migracion estandar en SQL Developer consta de 4 pasos:

1. Capturar
2. Convertir
3. Generar
4. Data Move

Por lo que veo te falto completar el 4to paso donde mueves los datos. En este [LINK](https://es.slideshare.net/ValentinTabacaru/sql-developer-database-migration) te adjunto una publicacion muy completa que te dara la guia para lograr lo que necesitas.

Comment: Ese manual esta anticuado

Comment: @Master quiza en version pero en el concepto de lo que necesita esta claro y es lo importante.